# Create 3d matrix from 3 vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 3 vectors, named a, b and c and I want to create 3D matrix, M, so that M(i,j,k) = a(i) + b(j) + c(k), where a(i) means ith element of vector a, and likewise for all vectors and matrix.

For creating 2d matrix, it is easy like a+b'. but I am not sure how I can create 3d matrix.

Comment: It's always good to mention explicitly what the shape of your original vectors (row or column) is. Please also note that the transpose operator in MATLAB is `.'` and not `'` (which is complex conjugate transpose).

Comment: @Dev-iL Sorry, they are all column vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) or [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to do the multi-dimensional equivalent of transposition:

```
a + b.' + reshape(c, 1, 1, []);
```

Assuming that `a`, `b`, `c` are column vectors of sizes `L`×`1`, `M`×`1` and `N`×`1`, this works because

- `a` is `L`×`1`, or [equivalently](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/521706-why-does-size-x-100-return-1#answer_429171) `L`×`1`×`1`;
- `b.'` is `1`×`M`×`1`;
- `reshape(c, 1, 1, []` is `1`×`1`×`N`.

So, by [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) the result is an `L`×`M`×`N` 3D array.